# Why this TensorFlow graph doesn't match with the code?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Below is some hello world level tf code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def model():
    layer1 = layer('layer1', None)
    output_layer = layer('output_layer', layer1)
    print(tf.get_variable_scope().name) # print 1
    return output_layer

def layer(scope_name, x):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name):
        print(tf.get_variable_scope().name) # print 2
        w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32,
                            initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=1))
        if x is not None:
            return w + x
        else:
            return w

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.variable_scope('model') as scope:
        prediction_1 = model()
        scope.reuse_variables()
        prediction_2 = model()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('log', graph=sess.graph)
        init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        sess.run(init_op)
        [p1, p2] = sess.run([prediction_1, prediction_2])
        print('p1={} p2={}'.format(p1, p2))
        summary_writer.close()
```

The `print 1` and `print 2` in the above code produces:

```
model/layer1
model/output_layer
model
model/layer1
model/output_layer
model
```

which is what I expected, but the graph it produced:

[model's graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqRsM.png)

has two `output_layer` in it, why there is a `output_layer_1`?